Different size between raster and shape
I have a problem trying to manage spatial data. I download the Birds of the World distribution shapefiles provided by BirdLife International and I have the cropland dominance from NASA data (available here https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20240514ACOqPMXO). So, the problem is, that despite I put them in the same projection (54034 - World_Cylindrical_Equal_Area), raster file has different size, it's bigger than shapefile. I tried to reproject but with no results.
Raster.


Shapefile.
Shape


How did you put these files into the same projection? your raster looks to be in metres and the shapefile in degrees.

I used the reprojection tool in QGIS. I can't upload a new image, but I edited the original post to show you.

Well. I fix it. I change the shapefile CRS. Thank you.
